# Fix suggested applications list in the profile settings

Tags: feature-request, preferences

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/apps/current

If you have no authorized applications, suggestions are shown on this page.

> [image]

1. [Stack Alert](https://stackapps.com/q/2874/55022) is not accessible anymore.
2. Same for [Stack Remote](https://stackapps.com/q/3178/55022).

Could you fix this list?